# What is a minimum valid robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

I don't like that I see a lot of 404 errors in the *access.log* of my web server. I'm getting those errors because crawlers try to open a *robots.txt* file, but couldn't find any. So I want to place a simple *robots.txt* file that will prevent the 404 errors from appearing in my log file.

What is a minimum valid *robots.txt* file that will allow everything on the site to be crawled?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As indicated [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), create a text file named *robots.txt* in the top-level directory of your web server. You can leave it empty, or add:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

If you want robots to crawl *everything*. If not, then see the above link for more examples.

Comment: Why add "Disallow:" and not just "Allow: *"?

Comment: @Patrik "Allow" is for overriding any previous "Disallow" directives. It is meaningless if there is no "Disallow". Honestly the best solution is a blank file.

Comment: Ah, I see. I also agree that a blank file is the best.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Because "Allow" is not in robots.txt specification.

Comment: @user11153: Huh? What about section "3.2.2 The Allow and Disallow lines" of the [1997 Internet Draft specification A Method for Web Robots Control](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt)?

Answer (score 7):

**The best minimal `robots.txt` is a completely empty file.**

Any other "null" directives such as an empty `Disallow` or `Allow: *` are not only useless because they are no-ops, but add unneeded complexity.

If you don't want the file to be completely empty - or you want to make it more human-readable - simply add a comment beginning with the `#` character, such as `# blank file allows all`. Crawlers ignore lines starting with `#`.

Answer (score -1):

I would say this;

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

It will allow Google to crawl everything but will disallow Google to Crawl your aadminn panel. Which is an ideal situation for you.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't think the asker said they are using Wordpress.